# Configuration modules

Tags: c#, configuration

I started writing a new framework in C# which can be used for any server development. It contains the basic stuff, such as database, TCP and configuration. I did write the configuration last night and I would love to get some constructive criticism and tips on it.

I know I didn't document the code yet, planning on doing it once I'm 100% happy with it.

First off, we have the `BaseConfiguration` class. This class is basically the base (superclass) of all configuration modules.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace AuroraFramework.Configuration
{
    public abstract class BaseConfiguration
    {
        private readonly string filePath;
        private JObject jsonSettings;

        protected BaseConfiguration(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            ReadFile();
        }

        private void ReadFile()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

            jsonSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        protected T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            return jsonSettings[key].Value<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is simple. It reads the file you pass down in the constructor, and 'converts' it into a `JObject`. That `JObject` is used to get values from. Then the `Get` function is used to get values from the `JObject` and return it in the right datatype. The reason I chose for this is to have more control than when I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TYPE>(string)`.

The whole class is used to it's easy to implement new configuration modules without reading the whole file on your own and without writing much code.

Next, we have the `DatabaseConfiguration` class, which is simply one of the configuration modules in the framework.

```
namespace AuroraFramework.Configuration.Types
{
    public class DatabaseConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
    {
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }

        public DatabaseConfiguration() 
            : base("db.settings.json")
        {
            Server = Get<string>("server");
            Username = Get<string>("username");
            Password = Get<string>("password");
            Database = Get<string>("database");
        }
    }
}
```

This simply uses the `BaseConfiguration` class as superclass. This will let the superclass read the file and convert it to a `JObject`. The only thing for the configuration module itself to do is call the `Get` function on every property.

And then, you use `DatabaseConfiguration dbConfig = new DatabaseConfiguration()` in the framework and pass it down to the classes that need to use the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want the properties of `DatabaseConfiguration` to be settable?

> `public string Server { get; set; }`

---

If time is not an issue, I would make the call of each property "lazy":

```
public string Server => Get<string>("server");
```

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot! Yeah, you're right. And what do you mean with `if time is not an issue`?

Comment: @Navine: I just mean the time it takes to read the property from the JObject each time for instance the `Server` property is called. BTW with "lazy" I probably mean "on demand".

Comment: Oh I get it, you mean it's called when you call the property? (just to see if I understand) Doesn't that mean it will always call that? I don't think it's much of an issue as it shouldn't really take that long and aren't called much.